# Lenovo Y50-70 laptop gives completely unresponsive black screen when opening certain websites and other random times

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, display, lenovo-laptop, black-screen-of-death

I have a Lenovo Y50-70 laptop and I have a really weird and frustrating problem. My laptop runs absolutely fine except when I take certain actions that include: Visiting a few specific website, going full screen on vlc and youtube, sometimes when running a game like secondlife. Then my screen turns absolutely blank/black with no cursor or anthing else visible. The laptop still runs absolutely fine in the background, eg responds to keystrokes, makes appropriate sounds and respond to other input but absolutely nothing will bring back the display to normal. I have to either put the system to sleep and wake up right after or restart it and then it runs completely fine until the next random event that triggers this happens.

What's completely baffling to me is that visiting the site www.msi.com will almost certainly give me a black screen immediately while the other causing factors are a bit random. I've tried the following:

1. Install the drivers given on lenovo's website as well as the latest ones for both my intel as well as nvidia gpu.
2. Reinstalled windows 10 several times, even asked a lenovo engineer to install a copy of the windows with all the lenovo drivers that come with the pc originally.
3. Stopped windows update because it was installing newer versions of the drivers automatically.
4. Tried various browsers, msi.com still almost always gives me black screen on IE, edge and chrome.
5. I changed the motherboard and my hard drive around two months ago and that's when the problem started. I've had the engineer check with a new screen and he says that when the hardware test shows the black screen to test, it doesnt come back from that even in the new screen.

Another thing is that it happens rarely when the windows has been installed fresh, but within a few hours as I install a few softwares that are must, steam, bitdefender, IDM, etc. it starts happening more frequently to the point that it will always happen immediately when I try to open msi.com.

My lenovo engineer has given up and he's saying as a last resort he can send it back to the main service center in another city where they will try to restore it to the factory settings and would take 15 days or so. He's saying since I didn't properly back up my original windows before my hard drive gave error and we were unable to reinstall it, and I made a reinstallation media from windows 10 website lenovo can ultimately say that I'm responsible and not help any further even though its under full warranty for another year.

At this point I might have to sell it at a huge loss and buy something else in a hurry and I would really like to avoid that. Hopefully someone here can help me out!

Update: I've noticed that the black screen on some websites only happens when my browser is maximized but not when it is restored or fullscreen. Ive also checked with various DPI scaling settings and have consistently observed this.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is more than probably a hardware problem related to the graphic interface. As you said, the problem begun when you changed the MB, meaning the graphic interface as well.

I would ask your engineer to replace the MB again.

Comment: I'm trying to get the mb replaced but it's really weird that it only happens when opening a few particular websites in maximized browser. Fullscreen and restored to less than half screen works fine. Do you see anything special in the site msi.com that would trigger this?

Comment: In Chrome Settings > Advanced try to turn on or off hardware acceleration. In Chrome again, if you are using Flash, try to disable it (in Content settings).

Comment: @spike_66 Tried with hard acc, flash and javascript on and off, no luck.

Comment: @Rhaldryn, not it isn't weird. You're probably activating some bogus hardware facility by going full screen with some web site...